# notification alert disable swift

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, notifications, onesignal

for testing I use OneSignal service for send push notification on my device and I handle it in AppDelegate in this way:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        OneSignal.initWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions, appId: “[app ID]”)//this method I register device on apple server

        return true
    }

func application(application: UIApplication,
                       didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject],
                                                    fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void){

        print(“ARRIVED")
        handleNotificationContent()// it’s not important for my question
}
```

My problem is that when I receive a notification and the app is in foreground , alert shows automatically and I don’t want to show it.
How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

This code worked for me.

This is applicable for Swift 2.2 and Xcode 7.3.1

```
//Initialize One Signal using this code

OneSignal.initWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions, appId: oneSignalId, handleNotificationReceived: { (notification) in

     //Put your business logic here like adding an alert controller or posting an NSNotification.

}, handleNotificationAction: { (nil) in

     // This block gets called when the user reacts to a notification received

}, settings: [kOSSettingsKeyAutoPrompt : false, kOSSettingsKeyInAppAlerts: false])

     //set kOSSettingsKeyAutoPrompt to false
```

Comment: hi, may i just ask. do onesignal still supports swift 2.2? if i install it's pod in their documentation https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/ios-sdk-setup, would i still be able to download the pod supported with swift 2.2? or automatic it's updated version for swift 3? just asking ty

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `kOSSettingsKeyInFocusDisplayOption` to `None` in `initWithLaunchOptions`, to disable the automatic display of inapp alerts.

[**OneSignal Api Reference**](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/ios-native-sdk#section--kossettingskeyinfocusdisplayoption-)

Comment: When i use the above I get:  Use of unresolved identifier 'None'. Any suggestions? when I use false the error goes away?

Comment: @PeterdeVries this is what you need: `OSNotificationDisplayType.none.rawValue`